# PowerBI Embedded, Bookmarks pane not showing

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I don't seem to be able to get the bookmarks pane to show on PowerBI (PBI) embedded.
The following are the steps I followed:

- In my report in PBI Desktop, I have selected View > Bookmarks Pane and indeed I see the bookmarks pane in PBI desktop. I created one default bookmark and saved my report.
- From PBI Desktop I publish my report to the corresponding workspace in the PBI Service.
- To Embed the report I use Azure Power BI Embedded with dedicated capacity.
- If I look at the report on PBI Service, the bookmarks pane is not showing there...somewhat confused I can go to View and show the bookmarks pane again.
- For embedding I use PowerBi Javascript API 2.6.1 and follow the instructions on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Bookmarks) however, when adding the embedding script as per the documentation:

  report.bookmarksManager.updateSettings({
              bookmarksPaneEnabled: true
          });

Chrome gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: report.bookmarksManager.updateSettings is not a
>   function

I tried as alternative to include it in the embedding settings

```
var config = {
            type: 'report',
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            embedUrl: embedUrl,
            id: embedReportId,
            permissions: models.Permissions.Read,
            settings: {
                background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
                bookmarksPaneEnabled: true,
                filterPaneEnabled: false,                    
                navContentPaneEnabled: true                    
            }                
        };

        // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
        var reportContainer = $('#pbi-report')[0];

        // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
        var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
```

...and on this case there is no error but the bookmarks pane is still not showing on my embedded report.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please retry. There was an issue with bookmark pane, that has been resolved.

Comment: Sorry but I repeated the steps above and it still doesn't work. Is there anything I would need to do differently? Thx

Comment: Would I need to change the embed configuration to allow users to edit the report instead of having: permissions: models.Permissions.Read

Comment: Also if possible could you provide feedback on the error with report.bookmarksManager.updateSettings mentioned above ? My JS comes directly from the Github doc.

Answer (score 0):

For the bookmark error, please use the following code instead:

report.updateSettings({ bookmarksPaneEnabled: true });

We will fix the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code for reference:

```
                settings: {
                hideErrors: true,
                panes: {
                    filters: { expanded: false, visible: true },
                    bookmarks: { visible: true},
                },
            },
```

this should work fine